# Proper grind and measurement for a pour over coffee maker

Tags: coffee, grinding

I've seen different sets of instructions from different sources, and experimentation has had mixed results.

Right now I have about a level scoop of coffee for every 4 ounces of coffee and this results in a fairly good-tasting brew for a medium grind, but the strength leaves something to be desired.  When I have a finer grind for anything larger than a six-ounce cup, the coffee clogs, even when following suggestions to stir the mixture while I pour.  I have a "single-cup" pour over coffee maker.

Should I be using a different grind, different measurements, only pour up to six ounces at a time, or some combination?

Comment: 'medium grind' doesn't really tell us anything, unfortunately. You should aim for a grind size that gives you optimal extraction time - I'm not sure what you should aim for here though, since I'm not a pour-over kind of guy. If a finer grind clogs the filter, you should probably just add some more coffee. Using medium or lightly roasted 'artisan coffee' means you need to use more coffee than an italian 'burnt-coffee' roast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the best thing about the pour-over method is that you can experiment without wasting much.

A few more details about your equipment would help.  How big is your "level scoop," what shape are your filters and are you using paper filters?   I make mine with a simple plastic #2 cone filter holder and paper filters and don't have any issues with clogging with about 2 Tbsp of beans.

Are you using a proper grinder or one of the whirling blade style?  The blade-type can do a decent fine grind, but you can't get a consistent medium or coarse grind unless you have a burr grinder.

Even a fairly cheap kitchen scale should be good enough to get a consistent amount of coffee, I'd start with 2 Tbsp (~ 10g) of beans for 6oz of water and adjust from there.  Try more beans and see if a coarser grind gets rid of your clogging problem.

In general, a very fine grind combined with the extraction time you typically get in a pour-over will give you a bitter flavour.  With the beans I've been buying recently, I use a fairly fine grind, but not as fine as I'd use for Espresso.  Manufacturers of paper filters claim that they trap sediment which reduces bitterness.

Comment: I'm using a standard coffee scoop, so 2 tbsp.  My grinder is a burr grinder.  Good idea with the kitchen scale--I may try that.